# C# Interactive vs Immediate Window. Differences, purposes and use-cases

Tags: c#, visual-studio

These two windows look pretty similar to me, though I've found some differences in using them. Can somebody please explain what the main differences are and what purposes the windows serve?

Comment: The immediate window came first, and is primarily intended to support debugging (you cannot just start typing there if your project is a library, for example). The interactive window is there to show off the capabilities of Roslyn, the new compiler (current compiler, rather). You will search in vain for a clear delineation of when one "should" be used rather than the other. I tend to use LINQPad for all instances where you could normally use the interactive window, as it's even more flexible than that.

Answer (score 9):

**Immediate window** is needed when you want to do some manipulations in the context of your program *during the debug*. Use variables that already exist, methods, etc.

Also, **C# Interactive** comes from Visual Studio 2015 update 1 release. C# Interactive is a REPL Editor, i.e. Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop with an advanced editor.